# How to simplify this insert statement

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

So I'm trying to insert 120 rows into a new table and it keeps throwing "Query too complex" errors at me. It works fine upto 90 rows.

This is the query:

```
SQL = "INSERT INTO " & newtable & " ([" & sourceQ & "_" & master & "], 
    [" & sourceQ & "_" & fld.Name & "])" & " SELECT 
    [" & sourceQ & "." & master & "], [" & sourceQ & "." & fld.Name & "]" 
    & " FROM " & sourceQ
```

I have tried playing with where clauses adding `WHERE [" & sourceQ & ".Expr1] like ('Field09?')` but it still throws those errors.

I even tried a simple one that should work like  `WHERE [" & sourceQ & ".Expr1] = 'Field001'`, which should just be 1 row, but it still throws the error.

Anyone have any ideas?

edit: debug

```
INSERT INTO tblCalc ([qJoinKeyAndStudent_<>], [qJoinKeyAndStudent_0 1 0 1])
SELECT [qJoinKeyAndStudent.<>], [qJoinKeyAndStudent.0 1 0 1] 
FROM qJoinKeyAndStudent WHERE [qJoinKeyAndStudent.Expr1] like ('*09#')
```

Comment: Right before you execute this query, add a `debug.print sql` or a `msgbox sql` statement to see exactly what you sql looks like. Can you edit your question and add that for us? Then we can see the final sql statement right before execution.

Answer (score 1):

While Access is capable of handling spaces in field and table names, you need to encapsulate both the field and table names in separate brackets:

```
INSERT INTO tblCalc ([qJoinKeyAndStudent_<>], [qJoinKeyAndStudent_0 1 0 1])
SELECT [qJoinKeyAndStudent].[<>], [qJoinKeyAndStudent].[0 1 0 1] 
FROM qJoinKeyAndStudent WHERE [qJoinKeyAndStudent].[Expr1] like ('*09#')
```

Does that work?

Comment: it still says its too complex. I doubt it's the bracketing since if there are 90 or less rows it works fine. So I need to reword it somehow, but apart from adding a where clause I don't know how to do that. Plus the where clause didn't work anyway

Comment: Maybe it's the data.  Can you run the Select statement by itself without the Insert clause?

Comment: Nope, once again "query is too complex".

Comment: I think I've gotten that error message in the past when the subquery is really the problem.  I recommend checking out `qJoinKeyAndStudent`. Does it run all the way to the end? Is there a `Expr1` field or did you rename it? Is `Expr1` a string field?

Comment: Yes it does, yes there is, Yes it is. Like I said, its only when there are more than 90 rows that this throws me an error.

Comment: Ok, wow. I'm running out of ideas then. So the subquery runs fine, but the Select query is too complex when there's more than 90 records. Maybe `Expr1` isn't being translated as smoothly as it should.  Try dumping `qJoinKeyAndStudent` into a table (a make-table query is pretty quick) and select from that table instead.  What happens then?

Comment: tried this: `SQL = "SELECT * INTO aTable FROM " & sourceQ`. too complex. Wouldn't work if I explicitly set the column names, nor if I put in a where clause.

Comment: Ok, so it sounds like something subtle in your `sourceQ` then, so look at that. Given that it runs fine up until a point, maybe you are unknowingly passing dirty data directly into a function. Are you using any expressions and are passing strings with quotes in them? null values? Perhaps on the 91st record, you are trying to add a number to a string?

Comment: No I don't really do anything special. It just seems to be a limit on access queries or something. Anyway, i changed the qJoinKeyAndStudent query into a select into, and used the table that formed for my operations, rather than the query itself.

Comment: Good idea. Glad you found a way around it.